# Creating a Generic Ordered Linked List in Java, trouble using compareTo()

Tags: java, inheritance, linked-list, operator-overloading

[SOLVED]

I'm a C++ guy learning Java for (hopefully) an upcoming job.  As such I'm practicing implementing a Linked List in Java on my own.  I finished implementing a standard doubly linked list and it's working great.  However, I then tried to create an Ordered Linked List and realized the inability to overload the '<' operator was going to be a severe problem.

I've looked through other people's questions on this site but it still isn't getting through to me, so I thought I'd post my code and get an answered more tailored to what I'm doing.

Onwards..

The Linked List Class:

```
public class MyList<T>  {

/*** ~Public Interface~ ***/
       //insert, delete, size, print, etc.
       ...

    /*** Private Data Members ***/
       //node begin, end, T data
   ....


/** Private node class **/
//Represents the nodes in the list
private class node implements Comparable<T>{ //Don't know if this is right
    node next;
    node prev;
    T    data;

    node(node p, node n, T d){
        next = n;
        prev = p;
        data = d;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(T o) {
        return (data <= o ? 1 : 0); //Get an error still here
    }

          /** Iterator **/
               //iterator class
}
```

The Ordered Linked List Class:

```
public class OrderedList<T> extends MyList<T> implements Comparable<T>{ //Pretty sure this is wrong

public void insert(T d){
    if(empty()){
        push_front(d);
    } else {
        MyList<T>.MyListIter it = begin();
        int i = 0;
             //This won't work obviously
        for(; i < size() || it.current().compareTo(it.next()) == -1; ++i, it.next()){
                    //find node to place the new node before it 
                        it.prev() //Need to go back one since we went forward in the loopcheck.


        }
    }
}
```

Really at a loss here.  How does one achieve something similar to operator overloading so that I can finish this ordered list implementation?

I'm also trying to get a grasp on inheritance in Java, so if you see something wrong in that regard, feel free to chime in about that too.

Thanks all.

UPDATE:

Ok, I made the changes I thought I had to make but I'm still running into errors.  Here's the new code:

The node class within the MyList class:

```
private static class node<T> implements Comparable<T>{
    node<T> next;
    node<T> prev;
    T    data;

    node(node<T> p, node<T> n, T d){
        next = n;
        prev = p;
        data = d;
    }

    public int compareTo(T o) {
        return ((Comparable<T>) this.data).compareTo(o);
    }

}
```

Ordered List:

public class OrderedList> extends MyList{

Usage of compareTo:

```
if(((Comparable<T>) it).compareTo(it.next()) == -1) found = true;
```

The compiler forced me to do those casts and now the error is:

```
MyList$MyListIter cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

List iterator class looks like:

```
public class MyListIter{
```

And it's inside MyList.

EDIT [SOLVED]

When I was using my iterator, instead of doing it.current() to access the actual data, i was doing it.compareTo(..), but of course my iterator isn't the data and thus doesn't know anything about compareTo().

Comment: You never declare the type parameter `T`; though, what you really want is to implement `Comparable<node<T>>`. Since you want your elements to also be `Comparable`, you should probably specify that e.g. `OrderedList<T extends Comparable<T>>`; you don't need to have `OrderedList` implement `Comparable` itself.

Comment: Also, it should probably be `Node<T>`, not `node`.

Comment: Some of your code is borched by the HTML because you have one two few spaces before it (under the "Ordered List:" title). Also, what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, you cannot overload operators in Java. This means that your sorted list **cannot ever use <= to compare objects of any kind**. Rather, you need to rely on the data object to have a `compareTo()` method or provide a way for the user of your list to give a `Comparator` object. If you wish to strictly limit your list to the first case, you can declare it as

```
public class OrderedList<T implements Comparable<T>> extends MyList<T>
```

This will guarantee that the objects inserted into your list have a `compareTo()` method. Now your `Node.compareTo()` function simply delgates the comparison to this method:

```
public int compareTo(T o) {  
    return this.data.compareTo(o.data);
}
```

Allowing custom `Comparator`s can get a little tricky. I suggest you leave that for after you get a default comparison to work.

p.s. Do you want to be able to compare lists to each other? If so, then having `OrderedList` implement `Comparable` makes sense. However, you might want to leave this for a later exercise after you have your list class working with its basic operations.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful.  I have more problems now with my iterator and compareTo().  OP is updated.

Answer (score 3):

While this is good as an exercise, I wouldn't hire someone who a) preferred to use their own LinkedList to the built in one b) used LinkedList as a sorted collection when there are sorted collections and ArrayList which is more efficient for this sort of this.. ;)

I suggest you read the source for LinkedList, ArrayList and TreeSet to get a feel of how these are implemented in the JDK. I also suggest you read the source for all the classes and interfaces in `java.lang.` and `java.util.`

You want to make the Node comparable to other nodes and you need your data type to be comparable as well. You should also use Java code conventions.

```
public class MyList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
```

---

```
static class Node {
    Node prev, next;
    T    data;

    Node(Node p, Node n, T d){
        next = n;
        prev = p;
        data = d;
    }
}

public void insert(T d){
    if(empty()){
        push_front(d);
        return;
    }
    for (Node<T> node = first;node.next != null; node = node.next) {
       // if less than we need to insert before.
       if (d.compareTo(node.data) < 0) {
          if (node == first) {
              first = new Node(null, first, d);
              node.prev = first;
          } else {
              node = new Node(node.prev, node, d);
              node.prev.next = node;
          }
          return;
       }
```

Comment: I'm implementing it purely for learning purposes.  Obviously I wouldn't be implementing my own damn basic data structures from the ground up on the job.

Could you explain the <T extends Comparable<T>> from a conceptual standpoint.  Coming from C++ this makes no sense at all.

Comment: Actually implementing singly or doubly linked lists is a common interview question so its not such a bad idea for an interview. Sorted linked lists I haven't come across. Reading the source for Java is one of the best/fastest ways to learn the tricky stuff.

Comment: `<T extends Comparable<T>>` means; I have a type `T` which *implements* Comparable so it can be compared with other objects and what it can be compared with is other `T`.

Comment: Apart from needing to use `compareTo` and not having `*` you should be able to write the same code in C++.

Comment: Just a heads up, I updated the OP with some additional issues.  Thanks again.